# How can I bind multiple actions to a single Angular output?

Tags: angular, binding, angular-template, angular-template-variable

How can I bind multiple actions to a single Angular output, without creating any additional methods?

An example would be updating the value of a `formControl` based on an output from a custom component and also marking that `formControl` as dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind an **array** to the an output in your HTML template, which enables you to trigger multiple actions:

**Template:**

```
<ul>
    <li style="cursor:pointer" 
        *ngFor="let value of values"
        (click)="[myFormControl.setValue(value), myFormControl.markAsDirty()]">{{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Form Control Value: {{myFormControl.value}}</li>
    <li>Form Control Dirty: {{myFormControl.dirty}}</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="myFormControl.reset()">Reset Form Control</button>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    myFormControl = new FormControl(null);
    values = ['spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter'];
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ph4m7b?file=src/app/app.component.html).